playBackState state: undefined
i am trying to build a music player application on react,
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Pressable } from "react-native";
import TrackPlayer, { State, usePlaybackState } from "react-native-track-player";

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

import { playbackService } from "../../musicPlayerServies";


const ControlCenter = () => {

     const playBackState = usePlaybackState()
     // next button
     const skipToNext = async () => {
        await TrackPlayer.skipToNext()
     }

     // next button
     const skipToPrevious = async () => {
        await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious()
     }

      const togglePlayback = async (playBack: State) => {
       
        const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getActiveTrackIndex()

        if(currentTrack !== null){
            if(playBack === State.Paused || playBack === State.Ready){
                await TrackPlayer.play()
            }else{
                await TrackPlayer.pause()
            }
        }
      }
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Pressable onPress={skipToPrevious}>
                 <Icon style={styles.icon} name="skip-previous" size={40}/>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable onPress={() => togglePlayback(playBackState)}>
                 <Icon style={styles.icon} name={playBackState === State.Playing ? "pause" : "play-arrow"}
                  size={75}
                  />
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable onPress={skipToNext}>
                 <Icon style={styles.icon} name="skip-next" size={40}/>
            </Pressable>

        </View>
    )
}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      marginBottom: 56,
  
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    playButton: {
      marginHorizontal: 24,
    },
  });

export default ControlCenter

here on, in second pressable i am getting error on playBackState, the error is " Argument of type 'PlaybackState | { state: undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State'.
Type '{ state: State.None | State.Ready | State.Playing | State.Paused | State.Stopped | State.Loading | State.Buffering | State.Ended; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.ts(2345)"  , so please help
